# Accessing files through a physical path in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently I'm using Xamarin.Android to make an app of mine which needs to access some files physically on the phone and not inside the APK.

My files are currently located in the "Assets" folder of the project and marked "AndroidAsset", but the issue is I cannot get the path to these files as their embedded in the APK obviously.

My requirement is that I need to be able to access the files from my app through a simple path as I have a 3rd Party library that requires a Path to specific files that it needs to read.

Is it possible to somehow create a folder on deployment, where my files are deployed and accessible through a static path?

If not, what are some alternatives in terms of passing a path through to a 3rd party library that needs a path for specific files.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to programmatically copy the Android asset(s) to the Data or Cache directory of the app's sandbox and pass your library that path

Comment: @SushiHangover That makes alot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access a file from "Assets" folder you need to copy that file in below location-

**var documentsFolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);**

{    var destinationPath = Path.Combine(documentsFolderPath, "DesiredFileName.extention");

```
        var file = new FileInfo(destinationPath);
        if (!file.Exists || file.Length <= 0)
        {
            CreateDatabase(destinationPath);
        }
```

}

public void CreateDatabase(string destinationPath)
        {

```
        using (var asset = Assets.Open("YourFileName.extention"))
        using (var dest = File.Create(destinationPath))
            asset.CopyTo(dest);
    }
```

used below code to access file-

```
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); // Documents folder
    var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "DesiredFileName.extention");
```

if any thing else plsease let me know.