# MAUI: What build action for appsettings.json and how to access the file on Android?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

I created an appsettings file for a MAUI app and loading it in the IConfiguration using `.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration` on the builder from a MauiApp.CreateBuilder();  I can access the file in Windows but not when running the Android emulator. The code:

```
 var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                })
                .Host
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((app, config) =>
                {
#if __ANDROID__
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867588/accessing-files-through-a-physical-path-in-xamarin-android
                    //var documentsFolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                    config.AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
#endif

#if WINDOWS10_0_17763_0_OR_GREATER
                    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000474/how-to-load-app-configuration-from-appsettings-json-in-maui-startup
                    Assembly callingAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                    Version versionRuntime = callingAssembly.GetName().Version;
                    string assemblyLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory); //CallingAssembly.Location
                    var configFile = Path.Combine(assemblyLocation, "appsettings.json");
                    config.AddJsonFile(configFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
#endif
                });
```

Mockup project is [here](https://github.com/DanielRBowen/WebViewWithSendingPrint/tree/Maui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open issue [Add support for appsetting.json](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4408).

This code snippet from [issue 3446](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3446) is one work-around:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .RegisterBlazorMauiWebView()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((app, config) =>
            {
                var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                config.AddJsonFile(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly), "appsettings.json", optional: false, false);
            });
```

Note the use of [`EmbeddedFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.embeddedfileprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). This works with Build Action `EmbeddedResource`.

---

**UPDATE** in above code, removed use of `.Host`, now that `ConfigureAppConfiguration` is directly on AppBuilder.

---

**UPDATE 2** See [Yepeekai's answer for newer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72454227/199364). CAVEAT: I have not tested it though.

---

**UPDATE 3** [James Montemagno’s code to support appsettings.json](https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/). This link is from a comment in the open issue.

Answer (score 8):

As of GA of MAUI: Add 2 nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

then in MauiProgram.cs, add:

```
using var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("YourAppName.appsettings.json");
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();
builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

Reference: https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/

Comment: a.GetManifestResourceStream("jsonfile") is always null (stream is null), Even the file is added as an Embedded Resource. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay. figured it out. In "YourAppName.appsettings.json", "YourAppName" should be the namespace of the assembly, which is quite obvious for the embedded resources, but I missed that part :D

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work for me in a .net 7 Maui Blazor app

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

Make sure to set the appsettings file as an embedded resource in properties.

Comment: Nice, I did not have to add any Nuget packages for this. Works also in .net 6 Maui Blazor app.

Answer (score 3):

From .NET MAUI Preview 13, `Host` is removed (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/4505). The exact same code in the accepted answer may not work.
Until `appsettings.json` is supported by MAUI (I hope the MAUI team will support it), I make my `appsettings.json` an Embedded resource and load and inject the contents like this.

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// appsettings.json is located directly under MyNamespace.csproj
using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.appsettings.json");
stream.Position = 0;
var appSettings = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppSettings>(stream);

builder.Services.AddSingleton(appSettings)
```

This may not be the best way to load the file but it works and it's good enough for me.
If there is a better way, I'd like to know it.

References:
https://redth.codes/settings-json-files-in-xamarin-apps/

Comment: `Host` is removed but `Configuration` is added for `MauiAppBuilder`. While there's still no proper way, you can use `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile` as it is mentioned in the accepted answer, or in the format I'm using now (which works with custom root namespace): `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(App).Assembly, typeof(App).Namespace), "appsettings.json", false, false);`

Comment: Re *"The exact same code in the accepted answer may not work."* - I've updated the accepted answer, to match the Maui API change.

Answer (score 0):

Thought id add this encase it helps others, using @Yepeekai answer

In .NET Blazor Maui I found I only needed to use:

MauiProgram.cs

```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyAppNameSpace.appsettings.json");

   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(stream)
            .Build();

   builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

Then in the page @code or as in this example a page base class you can use

IndexBase.cs

```
  [Inject]
  public IConfiguration _configuration { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
           var settings = _configuration.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
           //Example usage:
           var foo = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<SomeClass>($"{settings.SomePram}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this official tip for get a .json file in your .NET Maui app

Note: your .json file must to be in this path Resources/Raw

```
async Task LoadMauiAsset()
{
    using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("filename.json");
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I recommend to call this method in constructor Page Content.