# How to get appsetting.json to the right directory on my emulated android phone?

Tags: maui

Firstly, I’m a complete novice in programming.
My task was to program an Android app where I can create a calendar entry in my Microsoft calendar.
I used Visual Studio 2022, .NET Maui, Microsoft Graph and created a functional app. It worked on a Windows machine, but I can’t get it started on an emulated Pixel 5 Android phone.

I get this exception when I try to start the app:
[exception at app start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJEfr.png)

I got a similar exception when I started it on a Windows machine, but I could solve this with this code:
[code for Windows Machine solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voew7.png)

When I try a similar code for the Android app, it doesn’t work:
[one of my try out codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igvgt.png)

I tried out different ways (Content, EmbeddedResource with moving appsettings.json to directory Resources\Raw, none) I found here on StackOverflow, but nothing worked.

I’m not sure if I’m going in the right direction or seeing the right problem because the directory of the exception exists in my project’s directory but not on the emulated phone. My “work” is now more of a trial and error instead of knowing what I’m doing.

I’m thankful for any help.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Code and errors should never be posted as images

Comment: You can refer to the solution to a similar problem: [What build action for appsettings.json and how to access the file on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280264/maui-what-build-action-for-appsettings-json-and-how-to-access-the-file-on-andro/72454227#72454227), the other method is that you can try set `<ItemGroup><EmbeddedResources Include="appsettings.json"><CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory></EmbbedResources></ItemGroup>` in MauiApp.csporj file. If the above methods cannot solve your problem, please add the main code of your project for reproduce help.